# Moving Files From Dropbox App to Music App

Tags: ipad, ios, music, dropbox

Recently my laptop was put out of commission. Since then I've downloaded some music into my iPad's Dropbox app. I would like to move this from Dropbox to the Music app, but I'm not sure of a way to do it without my laptop. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The only ways to get music into Music.app is to sync with a computer, purchase from the App Store or use iTunes Match (which requires a computer to get set up). Unfortunately because of the way iOS is architected it is not possible to take music from third-party apps or websites and put them into Music.app.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you'll need some computer to import the songs into iTunes. It doesn't have to be your computer, just one that can either sync the tracks to the device or get them into iTunes Match. Once you have the sync, you can delete your songs from that computer.

You can play the songs from Dropbox by streaming them locally using the dropbox app (or mobile safari if you save them to a shared folder) and it will cache the songs locally as long as you have room. But, it's not the same as having them in the music app which is sandboxed and can't see the dropbox files directly.

The only downside to syncing from a second computer is that you'll have to wipe the existing music or manage manual syncing until you have a computer again.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded [Tunebox](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tunebox-dropbox-music-player/id475688071?mt=8), it was $4.99. It doesn't allow you add songs to "Music" but it does allow you to play songs from your Dropbox when your device is offline or in airplane mode. It works for what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

It is virtually impossible to take your music from dropbox into iTunes only using your iPad. If you use a computer and drag them from Dropbox into your iTunes then you can easily sync your iPad to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export the what you want by going to the Dropbox app and clicking on what you want and then clicking on the symbol that has the arrow pointing into the box. Just be sure and click the symbol with the arrow going into the box and not the one with the arrow out of the box

Answer (score 0):

i dont think its possible yet..... to get music on the music.app you will have to buy on the itunes.app or sync on the computer

Answer (score 0):

From Dropfile go into iFile for jailbroken phones and go into your Media folder into iTunes songs folder. Drop the song into this folder and your song will be added to Music.app.

Answer (score -2):

Transferring a music file from Dropbox to the iPad is possible. You need third-party software that uses music files natively in iPad for it's own purposes, such as Pinnacle Studio, for instance, which is a video editing software. Obviously this software needs to be able to store and access music files! I have this on my iPad.

So you open Dropbox. You play your music file. Press the AirDrop icon in the top right hand corner (iOS 7). The menu drops down. In mine a second row contains 2 icons, titled Copy Link and Open In.

Press Open In. You get a brief window "Exporting". Then 3 software Icons, of which Pinnacle Studio and Evernote, and also DAW (sound software). Get the cheapest of the three!

I press Pinnacle Studio (around $12.99) and voilà, it opens in the media library. I could not get it to open in DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) and did not try Evernote.

Voilà, case closed!

Comment: I just wasted my money on Pinnacle Studio. It doesn't transfer music from Dropbox to Music app. Yes, it opens in Media Library within Pinnacle Studio for editing purpose. That's where it stops. It cannot export the file to Music app, only YouTube...etc.

Comment: It will export to GoodReader which is free.  GoodReader is an awesome PDF reader...  Note: This does not get it into the Music App but you can play the music in GoodReader directly.  It implements a file and folder UI like most non Apple computers in the world.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use the app, USB Disk. Again, tap, "Open In" in the Air Drop menu and choose USB Disk. You can play the songs there and upload to a computer later. At least you'll be able to clear your Dropbox space.

Answer (score -2):

For anybody who's still having this problem, there's an app called airmusic or something to that effect. Search "dropbox music" in the app store and it'll be the first result. It downloads the files and plays them.

Comment: Sort order in the App Store will change, also it doesn't really help if you send everybody to search in the Store for an app where not even the name is clearly known. Can't you add a link to the app you have in mind?

Answer (score -2):

itis possible, you download the AirMusic app on your iphone or ipad, 
you have the music in dropbox dont you ?  , go on Airmusic click import at the the bottom right, click the top right icon click , download selected or all items and it starts processing, after its processed you can delete the songs from dropbox and they will stay on air music "dropbox music app"

Answer (score -2):

Well, I think you can add them to music. What I have tried is opening a secondary device. I have been using a crappy tablet called a nook. The attachment is a photo of it. I think using a s contrary apple device and having your Apple ID and password the same than it should work via airdrop or mail.[image]

Answer (score -4):

I downloaded "eddy" today. It works great. Select edit then choose which file from dropbox to download. Once they are downloaded you can play them back when offline.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question being asked which is: how do you get the files in to the Music app? It's not possible.